# Libgdx camera not well centralized

Tags: camera, libgdx, orthographic

I'm trying to centralize my orthographic camera but the X aren't in the half of my virtual dimension. I mean: I did set my virtual dimensions to 350 width and 620 height, so if you centralize the camera you will get 175 at X axis and 310 at Y axis, but just the Y axis are centralized and the X axis are at 206.64583.

That's why I did on my show() method:

```
// Create the ViewPort
this.viewPort = new ExtendViewport(Configuration.VIRTUAL_GAME_WIDTH, Configuration.VIRTUAL_GAME_HEIGHT);

// Create the Orthographic camera gy getting the viewport camera
this.orthoCamera = (OrthographicCamera) this.viewPort.getCamera();
```

And this is from resize() method:

```
super.resize(width, height);

// Resize the viewport
this.viewPort.update(width, height, false);

// Set position of the Orthographic camera
this.orthoCamera.position.set(this.orthoCamera.viewportWidth / 2f, this.orthoCamera.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
```

All of these are in my mains Game class.

---

NEW: This is what looks like on the phone. If the cam was centralized, should not appear the black bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dQc0.png (I can't post image with my reputation)

Comment: `this.viewPort.update(width, height, true);`

Comment: It doesn't invert the Y axis? Anyway, is not working

Comment: It does exactly what you want. Thousands of other people have done it that way and I ensure you that it DOES center the camera. You are probably doing something else that breaks it afterwards.

Comment: I put an image of what happen

Comment: You will probably have to post a more complete code example of what you are doing. The given code here seems okay.